# How can I go to end of line in VS Code Editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is a shortcut to move the cursor at the end of the current line?

Comment: it is a key close to the key that moves you to the start of the line, have a look at the keyboard shortcuts dialog

Comment: Simply use the "End" key on your keyboard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

END button on the keyboard. In word wrapped cases you can use END once more to end to the actual end of the line.

Comment: man this is so underrated solution I have been stuck for hours thanks a ton!!!